# JavaScript equivalent of PHPs ord function

Tags: javascript, php

I have a string which is

```
�
```

If I use PHP to convert this using the ord method I get 239 as a result.

```
echo ord(�); // returns 239 as a result
```

If I use the javascript equivalent I get 65533

```
const str = "�";
console.log(str.charCodeAt(0)); // returns 65533 as a result
```

Python also returns 65533 using its ord function.

```
x = ord("�")
print(x)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this? I need that 239 result in JavaScript somehow. From my research `charCodeAt` seems to be the accepted equivalent.

Thanks

Comment: You can do a function described in [PHP's ord in JavaScript](https://locutus.io/php/strings/ord/). Check this as well: [phpjs/ord.js at master · hirak/phpjs · GitHub](https://github.com/hirak/phpjs/blob/master/functions/strings/ord.js)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman thanks - both options still return 65533 for me instead of 239.

Comment: Oddly enough even Pythons ord method does actually return 65533, but PHPs ord doesn't. Unfortunately I need the PHP result

Comment: Aha, okay, we need to see why PHP returns like that.

Comment: All versions of PHP return 239!

Comment: That is a 3-byte UTF8 sequence, and `ord()` operates on single bytes, in this case using the first byte. If you want to get the result `65533` which is the decimal UTF codepoint, then use [`mb_ord()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php) which is part of PHP's multibyte string handling lib.

Comment: That said, you should only ever see `�` in text that has been improperly encoded and/or converted and is indicative of preceding problems. `�` means "there was some un-representable nonsense here once, but now only this weird question mark".

Comment: Thank you - that makes sense. The character is actually windows-1252 it turns out. I actually need the 239 result though in javascript. I assume I need to somehow encode it into 1252 first?